# Как обернуть текст внутри label в тег?

Tags: jquery

Всем привет!
Хочу попросить совет. Имеется такой код HTML:

```
<div class="controls">
<label for="elements[06158ec8-ad32-4dff-8323-48d4eeeb1ff1][option][]muzhskoj" id="elements[06158ec8-ad32-4dff-8323-48d4eeeb1ff1][option][]muzhskoj-lbl" class="radio">

<input type="radio" name="elements[06158ec8-ad32-4dff-8323-48d4eeeb1ff1][option][]" id="elements[06158ec8-ad32-4dff-8323-48d4eeeb1ff1][option][]muzhskoj" value="muzhskoj">мужской
</label>
<label for="elements[06158ec8-ad32-4dff-8323-48d4eeeb1ff1][option][]zhenskij" id="elements[06158ec8-ad32-4dff-8323-48d4eeeb1ff1][option][]zhenskij-lbl" class="radio">

<input type="radio" name="elements[06158ec8-ad32-4dff-8323-48d4eeeb1ff1][option][]" id="elements[06158ec8-ad32-4dff-8323-48d4eeeb1ff1][option][]zhenskij" value="zhenskij">женский
</label>
```

Необходимо стилизовать радиокнопки (и чекбоксы, которые выполнены таким же образом), но проблема в том, что не удаётся обернуть значение самого тега label в хоть какой-нибудь тег.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это реализовать, используя JQuery. Заранее благодарен!

Comment: приведите пример ожидаемого результата

Comment: Значение уже обернуто в тег `label` и не нуждается в другой обертке, по хорошему

Comment: для того, чтобы стилизовать радио, необходимо значение label обернуть в тег span, к примеру. В моём случае, это значения "мужской" и "женский"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это дело находит все инпуты типа 'radio' и через after() добавляет указанное после них:

```
(function(){
  $("input[type='radio']").after('<span class="checkmark"><\/span>');
})();
```

А уже с этим можно начать делать свой стиль.
Можно на всякий случай добавить родительскому label-у класс radio, если у него не окажется такого класса.

```
  $("input[type='radio']").parent().addClass('radio');
```

```js
(function(){
  $("input[type='radio']").after('<span class="checkmark"><\/span>');
  $("input[type='radio']").parent().addClass('radio');
})();
```

```css
.radio {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default radio button */
.radio input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Create a custom radio button */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.radio:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the radio button is checked, add a blue background */
.radio input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the indicator (the dot/circle - hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the indicator (dot/circle) when checked */
.radio input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the indicator (dot/circle) */
.radio .checkmark:after {
  top: 9px;
 left: 9px;
 width: 8px;
 height: 8px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Бубу?<br><br>
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="moo">Да
</label>
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="moo">Нет
</label>

Или не Бубу? <br><br>
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="radio">Да
</label>
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="radio">Нет
</label>
```

Или: [JsFiddle ДЕМО](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/6v7fbkrd/1)

Comment: Вы говорите слишком очевидные вещи. Вы же видите код, правильно? И понимаете, что я его не сам пишу, он генерируется именно в таком виде уже. И значения label (в данном случае "мужской", "женский") не обёрнуты тегом, поэтому стилизовать не удаётся. Нужно именно значения обернуть в тег

Comment: Ой. Отредактировал...

Comment: Дело в том, что подобных радиоконопок несколько разных. Скриншот: https://prnt.sc/n3kvfi

Comment: Каждое значение надо просто обернуть в тег, с одним единым классом. И ещё момент. Желательно привязаться именно к классу самого label, у него класс radio

Comment: С третьего раза таки дошло... Снова исправил))

Comment: *Чтобы не копировать километровый CSS* - встроенный fiddle [можно сворачивать](http://prntscr.com/n3m12y)

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ) Воспользовался вашим советом, но, к сожалению, скрипт просто добавляет пустой span, вместо того, чтобы обворачиваить значение в тег.  Вот: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12bI0M8icxLdD4Iig2u5xfaZBoFe6DEnl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Так и не должен... пустой span добавляется, чтобы именно его потом взять и переделать в собственную радио кнопку (заранее скрыв стандартную). А слова "мужской" и "женский" и так находятся внутри label-a, их можно красить, менять цвет и размер через класс .radio {...}. Но всё же если сильно нужно обернуть, тогда... https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/24qe1sp5/

Comment: Да, обернуть надо сильно) но понимаете, мне бы желательно одним скриптом обворчивать значения всех лейблов с этим классом. То есть, подставлять значение, типа "женский", не вариант

Comment: Хочу извиниться, не разобрался сразу с кодом. Теперь дошло, всё получилось! Применю подобное решение и для чекбоксов, которые сделаны подобным образом! Спасибо вам большое за помощь!

Comment: @Zeus07 если ответ Вам помог и является решением, [отметьте его как решение Вашего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)